# ¿Cómo se manda llamar una función dentro de otra función en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy comenzando como desarrollador de software y necesito hacer un método de inserción en SQL, pero estoy tomando datos de una tabla para llenar arreglos y después pasarlos al controlador.  Mi función de Javascript es la siguiente:

```
    function AddURPCatalogos() {
    event.preventDefault();
   // --------------- Apartado para el submódulo de catálogos ----------------
    
    var urpsubmodulos = document.querySelectorAll(".urpsubmodulos");
    var urpcrear = document.querySelectorAll(".urpcrear");
    var urpmostrar = document.querySelectorAll(".urpmostrar");
    var urpmodificar = document.querySelectorAll(".urpmodificar");
    var urpeliminar = document.querySelectorAll(".urpeliminar");
    
    // Cada campo es convertido a un array bidimensional
    var urpsubmodulosValores = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < urpsubmodulos.length; x++) {
        urpsubmodulosValores.push(urpsubmodulos[x].innerText);
    }
    var urpcrearValores = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < urpcrear.length; x++) {
        urpcrearValores.push(urpcrear[x].checked);
    }
    var urpmostrarValores = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < urpmostrar.length; x++) {
        urpmostrarValores.push(urpmostrar[x].checked);
    }
    var urpmodificarValores = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < urpmodificar.length; x++) {
        urpmodificarValores.push(urpmodificar[x].checked);
    }
    var urpeliminarValores = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < urpeliminar.length; x++) {
        urpeliminarValores.push(urpeliminar[x].checked);
    }

    var ValoresGenerales = [urpsubmodulosValores, urpcrearValores, urpmostrarValores, urpmodificarValores, urpeliminarValores];
    var x = $("#AddURPCatalogos").valid(); // ATENCIÓN AQUÍ,

    if (x != false) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: '¿Desea Guardar?',
            text: "¡No se podrá revertir!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                var urp = {
                    URPUserId: $("#URPUserId").val(), // PRESTA SUMA ATENCIÓN EN LOS NOMBRES DE LAS VARIABLES, DEBEN DE SER LOS MISMOS
                    URPRoleId: $("#URPRoleId").val(),
                    URPModuloId: $("#URPModuloId").val(),
                    URPSubModuloId: $("#URPSubModuloId").val(), // A partir de este dato, se hacen las inserciones con los reemplazados que se declararon arriba.
                    URPCrear: $("#URPCrear").val(),
                    URPModificar: $("#URPModificar").val(),
                    URPMostrar: $("#URPMostrar").val(),
                    URPEliminar: $("#URPEliminar").val()
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/AddURPCatalogos",
                    data: { URP: urp }, // EL PRIMER NOMBRE ES LA VARIABLE QUE ALMACENA TODO EN EL CONTROLADOR, LA SEGUNDA ES LA QUE ESTÁ DECLARADA EN LA NOTA ANTERIOR
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#btnAddURPCatalogos").prop("disabled", true); // ES EL NOMBRE DE TU BOTÓN EN LA PARTE DE HTML, LOS NOMBRES DEBEN DE SER IGUALES
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Guardando...',
                            allowEscapeKey: true,
                            allowOutsideClick: true,
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            onOpen: () => {
                                Swal.showLoading();
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    complete: function (data) {
                        swal({
                            type: 'success',
                            title: '¡Listo!.',
                            text: "Se ha guardado con éxito"
                        }).then((result) => {
                            location.reload();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

y mi controlador de C# es el siguiente:

```
[HttpPost("AddURPCatalogos")]
        public IActionResult AddURPCatalogos(CatUsuariosRolesPermisos URP)
        {
            try
            {
                if (URP != null)
                {
                    


                    List<CatUsuariosRolesPermisos> urp = new List<CatUsuariosRolesPermisos>();
                    
                    foreach(var item in urp)
                    {
                        item.URPId = URP.URPId;
                        item.URPUserId = URP.URPUserId;
                        item.URPRoleId = URP.URPRoleId;
                        item.URPModuloId = URP.URPModuloId;
                        item.URPSubModuloId = URP.URPSubModuloId;
                        item.URPCrear = URP.URPCrear;
                        item.URPMostrar = URP.URPMostrar;
                        item.URPModificar = URP.URPModificar;
                        item.URPEliminar = URP.URPEliminar;
                        _context.CatUsuariosRolesPermisos.Add(item);
                    }
                    
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    var x = _context.CatUsuariosRolesPermisos.Include(x => x.URPUserId).Where(x => x.URPUserId == URP.URPUserId).First();
                    var obj = new
                    {
                        x.URPId,
                        x.URPUserId,
                        x.URPRoleId,
                        x.URPModuloId,
                        x.URPCrear,
                        x.URPModificar,
                        x.URPMostrar,
                        x.URPEliminar
                         
                    };
                    return Ok(URP);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Esa es una de las funciones que necesito mandar llamar en una función. Son aproximadamente 5 funciones similares las que tengo que introducir en una función. Lo necesito hacer de esta manera porque en la parte de HTML manejo un:

```
<form id="AddURP" asp-controller="UsuariosRolesPermisos" asp-action="Add" method="POST">
```

ya que hay un par de valores fuera de las tablas de las que tomo los datos que necesito pasar para el método de inserción.
Y como estoy haciendo una validación por Id para que me muestre u oculte tabs, no puedo meter los datos dentro de una función independiente ya que no se mostrarían las tabs dentro del modal que tengo.

Comment: Para llamar una función de JavaScript dentro de otra solo la invocas como una línea mas, funcion1()  {  ...   funcion2(parametro1, parametro2)  ...   } ó ¿quieres llamar un función de  de C# con JavaScript?

Comment: Lo que necesito es realizar mis funciones correspondientes... y mandarlas llamar en la función principal. Por ejemplo, sé que en c++ puedes declarar tus funciones y solo mandarlas llamar en el int main, pero en javascript no sé cómo se hace, porque las funciones que mandarán llamar el controlador de C#, no retornarían parámetros a la función principal, sino que, pasarían los datos al controlador de C#

Comment: El consejo que me das es el que he estado usando para la inserción en tablas que sirven como catálogos. Pero como ahora estoy tomando los valores de una tabla de html como datos de entrada... y tengo una validación onchange en un select para que me muestre u oculte tabs, necesito segmentarlo en funciones individuales y unirlas en una sola con la validación del onchange. Pero no sé cómo unirlas en una sola, porque cada función tiene su URL y me marca GET 405 al momento de mandarlas llamar.